# EntityFrameworkCore. Подскажите по модели БД

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Планирую модель БД и столкнулся с тем что у меня много связей между 3 таблицами со следующей зависимостью:

1-ая таблица базовая, 2-ая таблица дополнение первой таблицы уникальными свойствами, 3-я таблица хранит коллекцию элементов 2-ой таблицы.

Пример

```
// Станция. базовая таблица
public class StationDto : IEntitie
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int EcpCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public ICollection<StationsRouteDto> StationsRouteDto { get; set; }  //Один ко многим с StationsRouteDto
}


//Станция учавствующая в построении маршрута. дополнение станции.
public class StationsRouteDto : IEntitie
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool IsLanding { get; set; }                                               //флаг посадки.

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime? ArrivalTime { get; set; }                                         //Время прибытия поезда на станцию

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime? DepartureTime { get; set; }                                       //Время отправления поезда со станции


    public int StationDtoId { get; set; }
    public StationDto StationDto { get; set; }                                         //Станция

    public ICollection<RegShStationsRouteRoutes> RegShRoutes{ get; set; }               //Расписание, в которые входят данные станции
}


//Расписание. хранит коллекцию дополненных станций.
public class RegulatoryScheduleDto : IEntitie
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Много настроек............

    public ICollection<RegShStationsRouteRoutes> Route { get; set; }          //маршрут
}


//промежуточная таблица для связи многие ко многим. через 2-е связи 1 ко многим.
public class RegShStationsRouteRoutes
{
    public int RegShId { get; set; }
    public RegulatoryScheduleDto RegulatoryScheduleDto { get; set; }

    public int StatRouteId { get; set; }
    public StationsRouteDto StationRouteDto { get; set; }
}
```

Изначально имею заполненный список станций(StationDto).
Необходимо создавать строчки расписания (RegulatoryScheduleDto).

ШАГИ:
1. Выбираю из списка StationDto.

2. На базе выбранного объекта создаю StationsRouteDto, заполняя IsLanding, ArrivalTime, DepartureTime
3. Выполняю поиск по совпадению всех значений созданного объекта StationsRouteDto в БД.
   Если станция с такими настройками уже есть, то присваиваю ID найденной станции своему созданному объекту.
4. Таким образом (создавая новые StationsRouteDto или используя уже добавленные в бд) создаю List.
5. Создаю объект RegulatoryScheduleDto, заполняя все настройки кроме Route.
6. На базе созданного списка List создаю список RegShStationsRouteRoutes используя созданный объект RegulatoryScheduleDto для связи M2M.
7. В объект расписания RegulatoryScheduleDto делаю присвоение св-ву Route, только что созданной проекцией списка в пункте 6.
8. Делаю Save в БД.

Правильно ли я расписал шаги, или можно сделать оптимальнее?
Т.е. код EF будет много, я думаю целесообразно сделать сервисов по доступу к данным и скрыть туда всю работу с репозиторием?

Comment: Предметная область сложная, описана кратко: вам может и понятно, а другим - не факт. Вопрос у вас очень комплексный, я бы не рискнул отвечать, не поняв предметную область. Вот вы описывает какой-то веб-интерфейс, верно? А зачем тогда усложняет себе жизнь тем, что обьединяете сценарий создания новой точки и сценарий выбора точки из дропдауна?

Comment: Планируется сделать сервис слоя доступа к данным, в котром будет скрыт доступ через EF. И наружу будет выставлен ICollection, вместо IQuerible. Этим сервисом будут пользоваться как WEB так и возможно Desctop.  Я попытался описать как к уже созданной станции я добавляю эксклюзивные св-ва и добавляю ее к маршруту. В начале вопроса я описал обшую проблему: "1-ая таблица базовая, 2-ая таблица дополнение первой таблицы уникальными свойствами, 3-я таблица хранит коллекцию элементов 2-ой таблицы." И хотел услышать свои соображения на то как лучше с этим работать.

Comment: Если вы говорите, что у вас есть *сервис*,  то опишите какие *контракты* поддерживает сервис. Из *текстового описания*, которое вы предоставили пока не понятно. У меня впечатление, что вы пока плохо представляете какие методы будут в API сервиса, какие и сколько. А главное -- что тот метод, который вы пытаетесь описать на самом деле нужно будет *разбить* на два, а то и на три. И *вот тогда* у вас код будет намного оптимальнее.

Comment: Я вижу, что вы начинаете путанно объяснять пользовательский сценарий ("пользователь выбирает из списка станций..."), а потом перескакиваете и описываете что делает код ("создаю StationRoute")  и в первых же строчках вы наговорили на несколько методов API, которые буду дёргаться -- а почему-то думаете, то всё это один большой метод, в котором будет "много кода EF". И вытягивать из вас эту информацию, просить, чтобы вы структурировали свои мысли... оно думаете это кому-то надо, кроме вас? вопрос поэтому и остаётся даже без намёка на ответ.